# Why helper link_to do not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to created a blog.And I have a model `post` and I want assign him, status 'draft'.For this I added boolean field   `field :draft, type: Boolean, default: false`and method in controller `to_draft`

```
  def to_draft
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id] || params[:id])
    @post.draft = true
    @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
```

and helper link_to, when I click to link, post assign draft status

```
  = link_to 'To draft', post_to_draft(@post), method: :put
```

rake routes

```
   post_to_draft PUT    /posts/:post_id/to_draft(.:format)          posts#to_draft
```

but interpreter show me an error

```
undefined method `post_to_draft' for #<#<Class:0x007ff7096ddd70>:0x000000064b5068>
```

where I do it wrong?

Comment: show the output of `rake routes`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post_to_draft` is just a route name.  You need to append this route name with either `_url` or `_path` to call the helper you are after.  Please reference linked [Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guides.

Update `link_to` call as follows:

```
= link_to 'To draft', post_to_draft_path(@post), method: :put
```

Comment: @vveare138 can you try what I suggested ? Let me learn it from your example.. Please try and let me know the result

Comment: are you talking about exactly? about helper or  query in mongo?

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it as

```
= link_to 'To draft', [:to_draft, @post], method: :put
```